# GPO Icons' / symbols meanings - Win Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy

What is the difference between those two icons? "Change the time zone" and create a "page file". Is that how they are inherited? or one is enforced by the domain while the other is a local setting?

Please help as the only documentation I could find from MS was for Windows server 2003. I am using windows server 2012. Would be nice to find an explanation for these icons/symbols somewhere..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The "Change the time zone" icon signifies that this user right **IS** being managed by Group Policy.

The "Create a pagefile" icon signifies that this user right **IS NOT** being managed by Group Policy.

Comment: Thanks! this not refer if the gpo is a local setting or a domain setting though?
Is there a source for this or something you have figured out own your own?:)